# How to dismiss only view on back key press not the whole activity in android?

Tags: android

In our application we have one parent linear layout which contains another linear layout as child.Child linear layout is nothing but treating as dialog box with fixed width and height. As expected if i click on back key of device entire activity is getting removed from stack. I just want if dialog box is open then only dialog box should get removed i.e. only child linear layout should be gone.How to dismiss only view not the activity on back key press?
Please do needful help.

Thanks,
AA.

Comment: override onBackPress() method of Activity and remove that Dialog from Activity. Don't call super.onBackpressed() until you remove the Dialog

Answer (score 2):

You need to override `Activity.onBackPressed()` and do what you need to do:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mDialogView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        mDialogView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could override `onBackPressed` to something like:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(!closeDialogsAndStuff()) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

private boolean closeDialogsAndStuff() {
    /**
     * check if dialogs should be closed and if so, close them and return true
     * otherwise return false
     * */
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement onBackPressed method(), and inside that method dismiss your dialog

```
    @Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
     // code here to show dialog
     super.onBackPressed();  // optional depending on your needs
     dialog.dismiss();
}
```

You can ask if you have any further queries :)

Answer (score 0):

put this code in your activity

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { //if user click back from device
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        if(dialog.isShowing()) dialog.dismiss();  //dismiss dialog if shown
    else finish();  //finish current activity
    }

    return true;
}
```